# Reading ID3 tag and values from a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have the following list:

```
ID3_tag = ['Title','Artist','Album','Track']
```

And I have a file called "This Boy.song" whose contents are as such:

```
[Title: This Boy]
[Artist: The Beatles]
[Album: Meet The Beatles!]
[Track: 3]
```

How do I return the value of a particular ID3 tag in This Boy.song?  For example:

```
>>> song = get_file_str('This Boy.song')
>>> search_ID3(Artist,song)
    The Beatles
```

Edit: forgot to mention.  I know that to get to the appropriate line, I have to use

```
def search_ID3(tag,file):
    for tag in ID3_tags:
        if tag in file:
            block
```

Or something like that (or I could be going about this totally wrong).  In This Boy.song, I know that each item is in a list, so maybe I use some list function?

Comment: "Finding and returning" is a poor question title. Try changing it to something more specific, for example 'reading ID3 tags and values from a text file'.

Comment: Ah, I suppose the title was rather bad.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you are looking for?

```
def get_file_str(filename):
    ID3_tag = ['Title','Artist','Album','Track']
    out = ['','','','']
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                (tag, value) = line.split(':')
                tag = tag.strip('[ ]\n')
                value = value.strip('[ ]\n')
                i = ID3_tag.index(tag)
                out[i] = value
            except Exception as e:
                print('Invalid data:', e)
                return -1
    return out

print(get_file_str('thisboy.song'))
```

Output:

```
['This Boy', 'The Beatles', 'Meet The Beatles!', '3']
```

**Edit**: You just edited the question to search for a specific tag instead of returning them all. This would of course be easily achieved by adding another argument, `desiredTag`, and return `value` if `tag` equals `desiredTag`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the name of that file format?  You should be able to find a parser for the file that will give you the contents as an appropriate Python structure (e.g. a dict or multidict).

Comment: It's a file format I made up, though I think I can play around with dict to figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> tags = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
...     for line in f.readlines():
...         if line.strip():
...              parts = line.split(':')
...              tags[parts[0].strip()[1:]].append(parts[1].strip()[:-1])
...
>>> tags['Artist']
['The Beatles']
```